# Is it safe to call a method on a FirebaseAuthClient instance before it's executed the callback from a previous call?

Tags: firebase

Or will it cause an error?

Example:

```
authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(baseRef, function(error, user) { ... });

// Try to log in...
authClient.login('password', {email: 'some_email', password: 'some_password'});

// Before the callback from the previous line of code executes...
// Oh wait, I forgot to signup in the first place, let me do that:
authClient.createUser('some_email', 'some_password', function(error, user) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is *safe* to call those methods before the previous one has completed, in that you won't break corrupt data nor will exceptions be thrown, you might see some unexpected (and non-deterministic) behavior, depending upon the state of the user's account and session.

For example, if an existing session is detected (via looking at the browser cookie and localStorage), the `FirebaseAuthClient` will attempt to resume it which involves a quick verification step. Calling `login` before that step has completed will have different effects depending upon the user's account status.

Continuing that example, if the account exists and credentials are correct, you'll override the existing session and your callback will be invoked twice (once for the existing session, and once for the new one). If the account does not exist, or the credentials are incorrect, you may first receive one callback for the correct session, and then an error after receiving the bad credentials.

It might be helpful to hear a bit more about your specific use case and desired user experience so we may determine the clearest way to structure your code. Hope that helps!